# SQL: Understanding the Difference Between These Two Queries

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have a table ("my_table") that contains information on:

- student_id (e.g. 123, 124,etc.)
- scholarship (1 = yes, 0 = no) : note that a student can receive a scholarship one year and lose it the next year (and vice versa) - but within the same year, a student can not change their scholarship status
- year_parking_ticket_recieved (multiple parking tickets can be received by the same student in the same year)
- year_parking_ticket_paid (the year in which a ticket is paid must always be greater than or equal to the year in which the ticket was received)

The table looks like this:

```
 student_id scholarship year_parking_ticket_received year_parking_ticket_paid
1          1           1                         2010                     2015
2          1           1                         2011                     2015
3          1           0                         2012                     2016
4          1           1                         2012                     2016
5          2           0                         2020                     2023
6          2           0                         2021                     2023
7          2           0                         2018                     2023
8          2           0                         2017                     2023
```

**I am trying to create a summary that shows how many students (scholarship = 1 vs scholarship = 0) paid exactly how many parking tickets per year (i.e. year_paid).** As an example:

- In 2010, 23 distinct students with scholarships each paid exactly 1 ticket
- In 2010, 13 distinct students with scholarships each paid exactly 2 tickets
- In 2011, 19 distinct students without scholarships each paid exactly 4 tickets
- etc.

The final result would look something like this:

```
  scholarship year_paid number_of_parking_tickets number_of_students_that_paid_exactly_this_number_of_tickets
1           1      2010                         1                                                          23
2           1      2010                         2                                                          14
3           1      2011                         3                                                          19
4           0      2010                         1                                                          20
```

**My Question:** A friend and I have been trying to figure out which is the correct way to solve this problem.

Here is my approach:

```
with cte as
(select student_id,
year_parking_ticket_paid, scholarship,
count(distinct year_parking_ticket_received) as distinct_year
from my_table
group by student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid,  scholarship),
cte2 as (
select year_parking_ticket_paid, distinct_year, sum(distinct_year) as count_distinct_year, scholarship
from cte
group by year_parking_ticket_paid, distinct_year, scholarship)
select * from cte2
```

And here is my friend's approach:

```
select year_parking_ticket_paid, number_of_parking_tickets, count(*)
from
(
select student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid, sum(scholarship) as schol, count(*) as number_of_parking_tickets
from my_table
group by student_id, year_parking_ticket_paid
) as a
group by year_parking_ticket_paid, number_of_parking_tickets
```

**We are both confused to which approach is the correct way to solve this problem - can someone please help us out?**

Thanks!

- Note: If Student 123 paid 4 tickets in 2010 ... he would not contribute to the rows for 2010 & 1 ticket, 2010 & 2 tickets, 2010 & 3 tickets ... he would only contribute to the row for 2010 & 4 tickets
- Note: The scholarship variable to year in which the parking ticket is paid

Comment: Do both queries get the expected result?  If so, how could either of them not be the "correct way"?

Comment: @ Tim Roberts: Thank you for your reply! All queries run ... but we are unsure which is producing the correct calculations...

Comment: Why are you “unsure which is producing the correct calculations”? The one that gives the correct result is the one “producing the correct calculations”. May be that’s not what you are actually asking - on which case can you clarify what your actual question is?

Answer (score 2):

The second (subquery-based) query is incorrect as the output doesn't distinguish between scholarship status.

The first (CTE-based) query is poorly-written because it shouldn't need a `distinct`, and should convert CTEs to subqueries.

Don't name a table `my_table`, ever. Don't represent the scholarship status as an `int`; represent it as a `boolean`. Also note that `scholarship` being on a table about parking records is a normalization failure, and should be moved to a `student` table; but I have not shown this.

```sql
create table tickets(
    student_id int not null,
    scholarship boolean not null,
    year_parking_ticket_received smallint not null,
    year_parking_ticket_paid smallint
);

insert into tickets
(student_id, scholarship, year_parking_ticket_received, year_parking_ticket_paid) values
(         1,        true,                         2010,                     2015),
(         1,        true,                         2011,                     2015),
(         1,       false,                         2012,                     2016),
(         1,        true,                         2012,                     2016),
(         2,       false,                         2020,                     2023),
(         2,       false,                         2021,                     2023),
(         2,       false,                         2018,                     2023),
(         2,       false,                         2017,                     2023);

select *, count(*) as n_instances
from (
  select year_parking_ticket_paid, scholarship, count(*) as n_tickets
  from tickets
  group by year_parking_ticket_paid, scholarship, student_id
) ticket_counts
group by year_parking_ticket_paid, scholarship, n_tickets
order by year_parking_ticket_paid;
```

```
year_parking_ticket_paid    scholarship     n_tickets   n_instances
2015                        t               2           1
2016                        f               1           1
2016                        t               1           1
2023                        f               4           1
```